# Pass PHP variable to src in HTML img tag

Tags: php, html, image

```
<?php
    $avatar_location = $_SESSION['p_avatar_location'];
    $avatar_location = "avatar/".$avatar_location;
    $avatar_location = (string)$avatar_location;
    echo "avatar location: " $avatar_location;
    ?>

<img src=$avatar_location alt="Avatar" class="avatarlogin">
```

I want to pass `$avatar_location` as a `src` but it showed me the as an error image, however it prints the correct image location:

> avatar location: avatar/avatar5.png

I've tried `<img src="avatar/avatar5.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatarlogin">` and it's working. How can I pass `$avatar_location` variable to show the image?

Comment: Use php variable like this in your src="<?php echo $avatar_location; ?>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<?php ?>` tag for your purpose

```
<img src="<?php echo $avatar_location;?>" alt="Avatar" class="avatarlogin">
```

Comment: @FirstSuchi  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

You must print your img tag inside `<?php ?>`

```
<?php
echo "<img src='{$avatar_location}' alt='Avatar' class='avatarlogin>";
?>
```